# How to create comments in Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I'm trying to create comments in my Azure Log Analytics queries and I'm stumped.  Part of my challenge I think is treating this system as if it were SQL, which it is clearly not. using "--" for instance results in a syntax error

```
traces 
| where severityLevel > 1
-- this is an example of a line comment
| where message !contains "DiagnosticsLogger.GetMethod contains message 1"  
| where message !contains "DiagnosticsLogger.GetMethod contains message 2"
| summarize by timestamp, message, severityLevel
```

Couldn't find anything for search term "Comment" either on the  https://docs.loganalytics.io reference.

Comment: use // instead. Btw, this is not azure stream analytics is it? looks more like azure log analytics

Comment: @PeterBons You must be right on the name, and it looks like the // comments work!  Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

// works for Azure Log Analytics queries

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: @sartoris If you look through Kusto Query Language docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ you will see that // is what should be used as a comment sign in example scripts, also if you look at "SQL to Kusto cheat sheet" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/sqlcheatsheet) you will see that there they are translating SQL's "--" into "//"... But if you are looking for specific place where documentation says "//" is your comment sign - I was not able to find this :)

Comment: @sartoris though you can also see an explicit statement in Azure Data Explorer KQL cheat sheets here - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-explorer-blog/azure-data-explorer-kql-cheat-sheets/ba-p/1057404

Comment: Another way to "prove" `//` is the way to comment - by picking a pre-defined query from the `Queries` tab. By double clicking one, the query's `KQL` is pasted in the editor, along with a description above it - which is prepended by `//`